# How to encode string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, encode

Im trying to encode with javascript some char string like "my personal email is alphabeta@mail.com" and then click it to decode, so far tryed this:

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="this.textContent=(function(d){let a='';(d.split('')).forEach(x => a += String.fromCharCode(~(x.charCodeAt(0))));return a;})(this.textContent)">ﾙﾞﾓﾌﾐ﾿ﾒﾞﾖﾓ￑ﾜﾐﾒ</div>
```

is there a better way ?

Comment: That depends on how you're going to use the encoded string. Anything you encode with JS on client-side is easy to decode ...

Comment: What you mean by encore? Encrypt? What is your goal? Prevent spam? If it's against bot, you must know that the bot just have to run js to have you email. Also a button click is probably not necessary, you could just put an empty string, and on load you decode a string and write the email.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most elegant way to protect something from bots is to put a Google Invisible Recaptcha.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible